# What is a generic word to refer to "icing"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, comida, español-neutral

Icing refers to a creamy, sugary topping used on cakes, cupcakes, to fill twinkies, etc.  It's typically made from butter or shortening and sugar, and often food coloring.

What is a word in Spanish to convey the same thing, which will be as widely understood as possible?

When I switch from the English page for [icing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icing_(food)) to [Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaseado), I get **glaseado** (glased), which isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Other words that come to mind are **merengues** and **turrón**, but neither one seems to be quite on target, either.

Some examples of icing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can only think of `pasta`

Comment: or `cobertura`...y `relleno` for filling.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid the there is no single term to convey `icing`. Actually if it is filling something (like *twinkies*) is called `relleno`. *Merengue* and *turrón* won't apply here.

If you don't want to go with `glaseado`, which seems to be the best option, you could make do with "baño" or ["cobertura"](http://www.directoalpaladar.com/postres/coberturas-sencillas-y-rapidas-para-tartas-y-pasteles) *de chocolate, vainilla*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Chile we say simply **crema** for any creamy coverage or filler.