# Si en México "betún" es una crema para repostería, ¿cómo se llama la sustancia para lustrar o brillar los zapatos?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, diferencias-regionales, méxico, colombia

Viendo por televisión de suscripción un programa mexicano de un concurso de repostería quedé desconcertado a conocer que en México usan la palabra **betún** para referirse a esa masa con la cual se cubren los pasteles o ponqués:

[image: betún repostería méxico]

Y resulta que en Colombia la palabra **betún** se refiere a esa sustancia pastosa tipo cera que se aplica a los zapatos para sacarle brillo, de hecho existe el verbo **embetunar** para referirse a la acción de poner o cubrir con **betún** un zapato y luego proceder a brillarlo con un cepillo:

[image: betún zapatos colombia]

En Colombia la sustancia alimenticia con la cual se cubren los ponqués se le denomina sencillamente "crema para ponqué".

Entonces en México como denominan la sustancia pastosa que se le aplica a los zapatos?
Qué palabra usan para la acción de aplicar esa sustancia y brillar los zapatos?

Comment: Pregunta relacionada (no sobre la sustancia para abrillantar zapatos, sino sobre el recubrimiento dulce que se pone sobre los pasteles): [What is a generic word to refer to “icing”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13095/5481)

Comment: **Betún** viene de **bitumen** que es un hidrocarburo que es exactamente la grasa que se usa para los zapatos. Los demás usos seguro aparecieron por analogía a su color y textura.

Comment: Esta pregunta me ha hecho descubrir la palabra [_ponqué_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=ponqué), ¡qué gracia que venga del inglés _pound cake_!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece ser que en México se puede usar "betún" para ambas cosas (crema para lustrar zapatos y crema dulce para pasteles) y es el contexto el que desambigua. De acuerdo a las conversaciones de [este hilo de wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/bet%C3%BAn.1028287/) se suele decir no simplemente "betún" sino "betún de chocolate", para hacerlo más claro y se usa "crema/grasa/cera para zapatos" para el abrillantador.

En Mercado Libre (web mexicana) puedes encontrar "[**Betún** Militar Camuflaje Táctico](https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-659304158-betun-militar-camuflaje-tactico-_JM?quantity=1)". A pesar de que no es el betún abrillantador de zapatos, está más cerca de este que de un producto culinario.

En [esta entrada](https://definicion.de/betun/) sobre el origen del término se explica sobre los nombres del producto en los varios países de habla hispana

> Si bien en muchos países de habla hispana se denomina del mismo modo [betún], este producto para mejorar el aspecto de los zapatos recibe otros nombres, como [pueden] ser los siguientes: en España, crema para calzado; en Venezuela, crema de zapatos; **en México, cera, cobertura o grasa para zapatos, aunque también, pasta para calzado**; en Argentina y Uruguay se lo conoce como pomada de calzado o pomada para zapatos.

Por último, en wikipedia podemos encontrar respaldo a esta afirmación, en su entrada de "[betún para calzado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bet%C3%BAn_para_calzado)", donde se explica que el término más común sería "cera para zapatos", siendo "cobertura" y "cobertura para zapatos" también usados en México pero no tan cotidianos.

Comment: En México es muy raro usar la palabra cobertura para zapatos. Como mexicano no entendería a que se refiere. Lo más usado normalmente es 'grasa' o 'cera' para zapatos.

Comment: @LuisBecerril Gracias. Wikipedia explica que el uso de "cobertura" es en México "no muy usual". Dado que eres de México, considera poner una respuesta para esta pregunta, si a la mía le falta algo.

Comment: cera, grasa y betún las he escuchado al norte de México.

Answer (score 1):

Variantes para referirse al betún, usadas en México:

- bola
- cera para zapatos
- cobertura
- cobertura para zapatos
- crema para calzado
- crema para zapatos
- grasa
- grasa para zapatos

En cuanto a la definición y acepciones que se indican en el *Diccionario de americanismos*, en las variedades distintas del betún asfáltico (o bitumen) y del utilizado para dar brillo al calzado:

**betún**.

- I. 1.    m. Gu, Ho, ES, Ch. Dulce hecho con claras de huevo batidas a punto de nieve y azúcar; con él se recubren pasteles y tartas o queques.
- II. 1. m. Ho, Ni. Pasta de arcilla roja diluida en agua que se utiliza para el engobe de vasijas de barro.